# Mi reverse-proxy no quita la cabacera X-FRAME-OPTIONS y no puedo ver contenido en iframes

Tags: nginx, iframe

Estoy intentado en mi web poder visualizar mediante iframes diferentes sitios web. Para ello me he configurado un reverse-proxy con NGINX para ocultar la cabecera X-FRAME-OPTIONS pero no funciona me sigue dando el mismo error. Para probar al margen de mi aplicación me he configurado un NGINX como reverse-proxy en un contenedor docker, os dejo el documento de confuguración a continuacion.

```
server {

listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ca.crt;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ca.key;

ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location /iframe {

    #proxy_pass https://trello.comm;
    proxy_set_header Host other-site.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
    return https://trello.com;

}
```

}

Como se puede apreciar la opción **proxy_pass** esta comentada ya que me retorna un 503 no siendo la solución para este proble como he visto en otras preguntas relacionadas